# Java Swing window not appearing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I have this code below to display a window using Java Swing. The problem is when I run the code in eclipse the window does not show. When I export the file as an executable JAR file and run it it works. Is there a bug with eclipse that prevents it from running it from there?

What am I missing?

```
package com.gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Calculator {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Calculator window = new Calculator();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Calculator() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    //frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Hello World");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    
    
}

}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure the eclipse knows it should be running this class and not some other class with a `main` method

Comment: Yeah I have the run configs in eclipse pointing to the right program and class. It just starts and says it is running but no window appears.

Comment: Add some work `System.out.println` statements to track the progress, see if it fails to reach a given point.  Try adding a break point and debug it

Comment: It works when I export it as a runnable jar file and then run it. Any idea why it does not work right out of eclipse when it is run?

Comment: Still sounds like eclipse is running the wrong class...

Comment: Try an run the class by itself to see what happens. Right click on the class file or the editor when the file is in view, and RunAs-JavaApplication. See what happens. If it works and it doesn't when try to run the project, then there's something wrong with your run configuration

Comment: just create new project and add the same code and run like that , see if problem persists , if  eclipse is still problematic try to re-install.

Comment: @peeskillet RunningAsJavaApplicaiton does not do it either. I definitely am running the right program and class

Answer (score 1):

Some projects created by Eclipse/WindowBuilder in macOS have this window-not-showing-up problem.

When an app is created through New > Project > WindowBuilder > SWT Designer > SWT/JFace Java Project, the new project automatically includes several extra jar files in classpath. Certain jar file(s) trigger eclipse to use special arguments (`-XstartOnFirstThread`) in the command (`ps aux | grep` to find out) when starting the application, and `startOnFirstThread` is giving us the problem here. AFAIK, `-XstartOnFirstThread` is added only in MacOS.

Solution 1: don’t use “WindowBuilder > SWT Designer > SWT/JFace Java Project” to create the project. You can just create a regular java project, and add the stuff you need.

Solution 2: remove the jar files. Right click on project > Properties > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries, remove org.eclipse.swt (removing this one suffices in my case, there might be others in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this is what worked for me (after the help of some folks on stackoverflow).

It turns out I had a library problem.  I had had imported all the jars in the .lib directory from jfreechart.  In reality only two were needed and some unnecessary ones were labeled swt and experimental.  Once I removed all the ones that were not needed, did a clean, and rebuilt, everything worked fine.

Oddly, changing the order of the jfreechart library (which included the conflicting jars) to the bottom did not help, the extra jars had to be removed.

Not a jfreechart issue, obviously my own library import issue.  So I suggest you try to remove some of the libraries that may be conflicting, then clean, build, and run again.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and the root cause turned out to be the extra .jar in the build path(using macOS). For me, it worked after removing the `org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3*.jar too.` part.